# How to use Ubuntu in full screen mode on virtualbox?

Tags: 10.04, virtualbox, windows-7, fullscreen

I have an HP laptop  with Windows 7 installed.
How can I use Ubuntu in full-screen mode via virtualbox or any other software?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- In virtualbox **[Host Key]**  **+ F** works for fullscreening.
  [image]
- By default your Host key will be **Right Ctrl** in VirtualBox.
- You can also change your host key,to change your host key open virtualbox and then goto File menu and choose preferences.
- In preferences choose input,you can see your host key there.
  [image]
- You can change it if you need.
- Also you have to install **Guest Additions** to enable full screen mode.

**Installing Guest Additions for full screen**

- Go to Devices and choose **Install Guest additions** on the top of your virtualization window.
  [image]
- Open the Guest Additions folder which should be on your Desktop in Ubuntu or in Places menu, and open Autorun.sh in terminal by double clicking on the autorun.sh file and picking **run in Terminal** from the pop-up window button options.Type in your password and wait a few minutes to install guest editions.
  [image]
- After installing Guest additions restart your virtual machine(ubuntu).
  [image]
- Now you will have better performance and bigger display resolutions.

Comment: in my case (VirtualBox 6.0) _Insert Guest Additions CD Image_ did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

While karthick87 explains how to put VirtualBox in "full screen" mode, you should also install `virtualbox-ose-guest-dkms`, `virtualbox-ose-guest-utils` & `virtualbox-ose-guest-x11` inside the virtual machine first.  (Otherwise only some basic low VGA/VESA resolutions will be available.)

Answer (score 8):

I had similar problem. I changed the resolution in display settings and now I have the full screen. I right clicked on Ubuntu desktop and selected Display settings and then changed the resolution to appropriate size. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

The new VirtualBox  version 4.0  has a new feature that allows Dynamic screen size setting (to match the host resolution) by just resizing the window (a feature VMWare has had)  and now the X11 config is not so important.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest edition of Guest Additions iso file and install them irrespective of the version of Virtual Box you are using.

Link to install Guest additins iso : http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/ Click on the latest version and then download the VBoxGuestAdditions_'version_'name'.iso file

After installing just restart your machine.! :)